# Orientation on boundary of a smooth open set

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary, $bD$, that is, for each $p \in bD$, there exist a smooth function $r$: from a open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $U\bigcap bD=\left\{ x\in U:r\left(x\right)=0\right\} $ and $dr\neq0$ on $U\bigcap bD$. Now $bD$ is a submanifold $(n-1)$ dimension of $\mathbb R^n$.

My question is, how to define the orientation on $bD$? that is, which is smoothly non-vanishing (n-1) form on $bD$?

Can everybody help me or give me a textbook which mentions about it?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be covered in any standard differential topology textbook. The one by Guillemin and Pollack is pretty accessible. This is covered on page 97

Answer (score 1):

There's more than what you say. $dr\ne 0$ on $U\cap \partial D$, as well. (I see you just edited to include this.) If you choose your charts on $D$ so that $r>0$ on $U\cap D$, then you can easily glue all these $r$'s together with a partition of unity to get a *globally* defined smooth function $f$ defined on a neighborhood of $D$ with $f>0$ on $D$, $f=0$ on $\partial D$, and $df_p(v)<0$ for any outward-pointing normal vector at $p$. This then defines an orientation on $\partial D$. (If you want a nowhere-zero $(n-1)$-form on $\partial D$, take $\iota_{v} dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ for $v$ a smooth, nowhere-zero outward-pointing normal vector field, as given above.)

If you want to read about the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem, which actually gives a stronger result (including orientability of any compact, smooth hypersurface in $\Bbb R^n$), see Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Thanks Ted, but I don't get your idea. Can you give more explanation about your notes?

Comment: What specific things do you not understand? It's hard to guess your background, because you're using rather sophisticated language to phrase the question.